# How to use a different entry point in ansible roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

Based on ansible documentation for [roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) I can make multiple role entry points by creating files:

```
playbooks/roles/my_role/tasks/main.yml
playbooks/roles/my_role/tasks/other.yml
```

And I can add the default `main.yml` role using this code:

```
---
- name: Example 1
  hosts: <hostnames>
  roles:
    - my_role
```

But how can I use the `other.yml` entrypoint?
I would expect it to be something like this, but none of those work:

```
---
- name: Example 1
  hosts: <hostnames>
  roles:
    - my_role:other
    - my_role/other
    - my_role.other
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `roles` directive in a playbook loads the default "entrypoint" of the role, i.e. `tasks/main.yml`. Other tasks files like `tasks/others.yml` can be loaded from it based on conditions, tags, etc.

However if you do want to load a specific file from a role, you can use the [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/include_role_module.html) or [import_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/import_role_module.html) modules.

E.g.:

```yaml
  # invoke role's default "entrypoint" (main.yml)
  roles:
    - my_role

  tasks:
    # include the role, but tasks from other.yml
    - include_role:
        name: my_role
        tasks_from: other.yml
```

*Do note the order of execution mentioned in the documentation you linked.*

Another "hacky" option is to use `include|import_tasks` modules which works just like including a simple "tasks" file (losing the roles functionality), if it meets your requirement.

```yaml
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: path/to/my_role/tasks/other.yml
```